# Why is Nginx proxy_pass ignoring add_headers when used with variables?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I am trying to make a dynamic CORS proxy using Nginx, so I can use multiple API's from my front-end code without any CORS errors. My current way is using multiple `location` blocks, one for each domain, which works, but I would rather have a dynamic solution. My idea is to use `x-proxy-target` to specify the upstream hostname, and pass on the pathname. Nginx is running in Docker containers on Kubernetes, hence `10.245.0.10` being the resolver.

This works perfectly, and sends the CORS headers that are set at the bottom using `add_header`

```
location / {
      default_type application/json;
      if ($http_x_proxy_target = "") {
        return 400 '{"message": "No x-proxy-target header", "code": "PROXY_TARGET_NOT_SET"}';
      }

      resolver 10.245.0.10 [::1];
      set $cors '*';
      if ($http_origin != "") {
         set $cors $http_origin;
      }

      if ($request_method = "OPTIONS") {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $cors always;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS" always;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers * always;
        return 204;
      }

      proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers;
      proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers;
      proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials;
      proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
      
      proxy_set_header x-proxy-target '';
      proxy_set_header User-Agent $http_user_agent;
      proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Origin https://$http_x_proxy_target;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_x_proxy_target;
      proxy_set_header Referer https://$http_x_proxy_target/;

      proxy_pass https://google.com/;

      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers * always;
      add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers * always;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true always;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $cors always;
}
```

But when I change the `proxy_pass` to use the supplied upstream:

```
location / {
      default_type application/json;
      if ($http_x_proxy_target = "") {
        return 400 '{"message": "No x-proxy-target header", "code": "PROXY_TARGET_NOT_SET"}';
      }

      resolver 10.245.0.10 [::1];
      set $cors '*';
      if ($http_origin != "") {
         set $cors $http_origin;
      }

      if ($request_method = "OPTIONS") {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $cors always;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS" always;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers * always;
        return 204;
      }

      proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers;
      proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers;
      proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials;
      proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
      
      proxy_set_header x-proxy-target '';
      proxy_set_header User-Agent $http_user_agent;
      proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Origin https://$http_x_proxy_target;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_x_proxy_target;
      proxy_set_header Referer https://$http_x_proxy_target/;

      proxy_pass $scheme://$http_x_proxy_target$uri$is_args$args;

      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers * always;
      add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers * always;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true always;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $cors always;
}
```

I get the correct response using Postman, but the CORS headers are not set. I have tried moving the `add_header` lines to above the `proxy_pass`, to no avail. To me, this seems like a possible bug in Nginx, although I might just be making an obvious mistake. I can't find any mention of this problem anywhere, although it is a very specific usecase.